# Finding centripetal force acting on mass

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

> A $0.2 \textrm{ kg}$ mass is being swung round a circle on a light string of length $60 \textrm{ cm}$. It makes $1.4 \textrm{ revolutions per second}$. Find the centripetal force acting on the mass.

My attempt:

[image]

Is the final answer correct ?

Comment: I think a calculator will be of better help than any mathematician!

Comment: Where did the $77.378$ come from?  It seems to have the wrong units, whatever it is.

Comment: That's is true haha but I mean are all the formulas correct ? Such as is w=2 x Pi x f is this correct ?

Comment: @Bye_World it came from squaring w.

Comment: OK.  Then your answer is fine (assuming you multiplied correctly).  But the units of $\omega^2$ should be $[s^{-2}]$ (because $\omega$ has units of $[s^{-1}]$).

Comment: Ah yes thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have given is:

Frequency($v$)=$1.4$ $Hz$

Mass$=0.2 Kg$

Radius$=0.6m$

Now angular velocity $w$ is given by $2\pi v$ or $w=2\pi v=8.8radians/sec$.

Centripetal force is given by $F_c=mw^2r$ which from the given data is $0.2 * 8.8^2*0.6=9.2928 N$